# How to create Zombie Process?

Tags: c, process, fork, zombie-process

I was writing programs to create zombie process (for purpose of learning).

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  int i = ::fork();

  if(i == 0) sleep(30);
  else printf("process %d/%d\n", getpid(), i); 

  return 0;

}
```

The above code call `fork` without `waitpid` on the child process. However, after launching this code I use `ps aux | grep 'Z'` trying to find the zombie process. I didn't see anything. The child process appears in the process list and soon after 30 seconds (`sleep`) it disappeared and I find nothing with status `'Z'` in the process list. Does this code actually create a zombie process?

Comment: You haven't created a zombie, you've created an orphan.

Comment: How can I create a Zombie in this case?

Comment: So, if the parent dies before the child, the child becomes an orphan (obvious enough). If the child dies before the parent, the child turns into a zombie until the parent `wait()`s for it.

Comment: Alright, I moved the `sleep(30)` to the `else` block so the parent die after child without `wait`. But again I use `ps aux | grep 'Z'` and didn't find any process with zombie status. What could be the reason?

Comment: What does the `sleep()` call in the parent return?

Comment: It successfully returns 0.

Comment: Are you executing `ps` while the parent is still sleeping?

Comment: Does this matter? I search both (sleeping and after sleeping) but no Zombie appears.

Comment: Well, I can easily get a zombie to show up. Maybe you should post your current code?

Comment: int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

      auto i = ::fork();

      if(i == 0) {

      }
      else {
        ::std::cout<<sleep(5) << ::std::endl;
        printf("process %d/%d\n", getpid(), i); 
        int s;
      }

  return 0;
}

Comment: Sry I don't know how to make it a code region in the comment block, but I guess you can see the newest code.

Comment: Wait... I just made a mistake and now I can see Zombie. But the status is only seen during the sleep (the lifetime of parent). After parent process exits the zombie status disappears. How can this be?

Comment: First of, this is actually c++, not c. Second, once the parent dies, any children it had (orphans and zombie-orphans) are made wards of the state (re-parented to `init`/pid one). `init` waits for all its children.

Comment: OK now I understood! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = fork();

    if(i == 0)
    {
        exit(0); /* we let the child die as fast as possible */
    } else {
        printf("process %d/%d\n", getpid(), i);
        sleep(30); /* during these 30 sec, the child is a zombie, because it is dead, but not reaped with waitpid yet. Use ps command during this to see it in the process list */
    }
    /* when we do not reap the child before we exit, it will either be removed by OS or reaped by init as it is reparented */
    return 0;
}
```